# Java Date Issue,Keeps Reverting To 1935 Form 2035

Tags: java, date, testing, restrictions

Having an issue with an application I'm testing that takes in several Date parameters from a user, while testing I've noticed if i enter a date that's in or before 2034 everything works fine but once i go from lets say 21/08/34 to 21/08/35 the year reverts to 1935, not 2035.

I'm using the java.util.Date Class to store the Data entered, any ideas? is there any known restrictions on the Date class that might be causing such an issue??

Thanks

Comment: How do you construct the Date-objects, please post some code?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same in Lotus Notes Development. I actually think it's desired behaviour.
It's probably a timespan (80 years from now in the past) on which the shortcut (34..35..70) is considered being used for the year you probably want to use.

I.e. You speak from the 70ies, but mean 1970, not 2070. If you speak from 35 you probably mean 1935, because its not too long away from today. But if you speak from 18, you'll probably mean the future, because its outside of the timespan of 80 years, but near in the future.

It's probably defined somewhere, **but this all is just an assumption.**

If you get dates from your users, be sure you get a YYYY date, so there will be no wrong entry.

**Edit**
My assumption seems to be right:

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){

    String first = "August 22, 34";
    String second = "August 21, 34";
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yy",Locale.ENGLISH).parse(first);
        Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yy",Locale.ENGLISH).parse(second);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(date2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

Where the output is:

```
Wed Aug 22 00:00:00 BST 1934
Mon Aug 21 00:00:00 BST 2034
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you use SimpleDateFormat and enter the year in the abbreviated form (i.e not the complete 4 digits representation).

If any of the last 80 years (past years) since the creation of your SimpleDateFormat instance , contain a year with the last two digits which you entered, that year is taken as the parsed value.
If the last 80 years do not contain this year, then the next 20 years (future years) will be used to represent this value.

Since '21st Aug, 1934' goes one day beyond the 80 years limit from today's date (21st Aug, 2014), the next 20 years i.e '21st Aug, 2034' is considered as the parsed value.

You can refer to this link : [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year)

(See the third bullet point under 'Year' section, in the link above.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem located in code that convert date from String to Date. 
I can speculate that you use SimpleDateFormat with wrong format string.